# a sequence of measurable sets in $A$ their intersection union is nul

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(\Omega,$A$,\mu)$ be a measure space ,Let ($A_n$) be a sequence of measurable sets in $A$ with the property

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$$\mu$($A_n$)<$\infty$.

Show that $\mu$( $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}$$\bigcup_ {m=n}^{\infty}$$A_n$)=$0$

Comment: Google: Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_m = \displaystyle \bigcup_{n=0}^m A_n$, $ A = \displaystyle \bigcap_{m=0}^{ \infty}B_m$; we want to prove that $\mu (A) = 0.$
Observe that the following estimate holds:
$$ 
\forall m \in \mathbb{N}\ \colon\ \mu(A) \le \mu (B_m) = \mu \left ( \bigcup_{n=m}^{ \infty} A_n \right ) \le \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \mu (A_n).
$$
Now observe that the $ \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \mu (A_n) $ goes to $0$ as $m \longrightarrow \infty$ because the whole series converges.